# Azure Integration Account Maps in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure Logic Apps. I have uploaded **Map** and Schema in **Integration Account** and assigned it to my Logic App project.

The issue is that I can see my schema and map in Logic App Designer view in  **azure portal**, But **not in my Visual Studio** 2017 Logic App Designer.
Screenshots can be seen below.

**Azure Portal:**
[image]

**Visual Studio:**
[image]

I have to use Visual Studio, its in our requirements. I don't know why Visual Studio not getting Maps/Schema in the list.

Any help please?

Regards,

Comment: Are you signed-in to your Azure subscription through VS ?

Comment: Yes, I guess. Because i can deploy my project, and can access some other functions from online portal in VS. So this means I am signed-in.

Comment: Are you using the same Logic App via portal vs. in VS? If not, is the Logic App used in VS linked with the integration account?

Comment: @DerekLi  Yes its same.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Logic App in Logic App Designer.
2. Press F4 to bring up the properties window
3. Select the Integration Account from the first drop down